# Perpetual 5 year cycle in a for loop

Tags: php

I'm working on a project where there is a 5 year maintenance cycle. There's a list of assets in a database table and they each have a year between 1 and 5 that they have to be serviced.

This year (2019) is 'Year 1' and is the starting point for the cycle. It's stored in a configuration file as the initial starting year. It's easy enough to create a loop that will generate the options in the select list for the 5 year cycle. The years are numbered:

2019 - Year 1
2020 - Year 2
2021 - Year 3
2022 - Year 4
2023 - Year 5

```
// Build years 1 to 5 based on 2019 start year
$fdstartyear = 2019;
for($i=1;$i<6;$i++) {
  $actual_year = $fdstartyear + ($i-1);
  echo '<option value="'.$actual_year.'">Year '.$i.'</option>';
}
```

The 5 year cycle is perpetual, so next year (2020) the list would look like this:

2020 - Year 2
2021 - Year 3
2022 - Year 4
2023 - Year 5
2024 - Year 1

...and in 2021 the list would look like this:

2021 - Year 3
2022 - Year 4
2023 - Year 5
2024 - Year 1
2025 - Year 2

I can't figure out how to generate the correct year numbers based on the current year and using 2019 as the starting point.

Comment: Sigh, why not use a date field in the database and configure the amount of time before the asset needs to be serviced.  That would be the simplest way to get the data you need and ensure your app works on day 1 of year five.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$start` is the year your maintenance schedule begins.

`$current` is the actual current year. You can hard code this to `2020` to test what will happen next year.

```
$start = 2019;
$current = date('Y');

for ($year = $current; $year < $current + 5; $year++) {
    $i = ($year - $start) % 5 + 1;
    echo '<option value="' . $year . '">Year '. $i . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Yep - that's exactly what I needed. I had it partly nutted out except for the year - start modulo part!